# Shiny: generating reactive dataframes before switching to tab

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I have a Shiny app that, upon initializing, reads a CSV into a dataframe with ~1.5M rows. This app has three tabitems. The third tabitem has several filters for that big dataframe, and a bunch of reactive data tables that apply the filters and show different aggregated results.

Because the app initially displays the first tabitem, when I switch to the third tabitem, the app then needs several seconds to do all the filtering and make reactive DFs prior to displaying.

Is there a way to force Shiny to "pre-calculate" these reactive DFs when I initialize the app, so that they're ready to go using default filter settings when I switch to the tab?